# Python Django How to hook inlines with model in admin

Tags: python, django

in `models.py`, I have Image and Post model defined:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # name is the slug of the post
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    width = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d')
    image_post = models.ForeignKey('Post')

    def get_image(self):
        return self.image.url

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    post_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null = True)

    def image_tag(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.post_image.url

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

in `admin.py`, I've defined as inlines:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 3

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'description')
    readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)
    exclude = ('post_image', )
    inlines = [ImageInline, ]
    list_filter = ('published', 'created')
    search_fields = ('title', 'description', 'content')
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    save_on_top = True
    prepopulated_fieldes = {"slug" : ("title",)}
```

In the admin page, when I upload an image in the Post admin page, the image is stored. But it's not hooked up with the Post. How to hook the image with the post when I upload in admin? I mean let the inline image uploaded become post's post_image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand thee is 1-to-1 relation between `Image` and `Post` models.  So you should use the `OneToOneField` instead of two `ForteignKey`s.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    post = models.OneToOneField('Post')
```

And the delete the `post_image` field from the `Post` model.

To access the image instance from the `Post` just write:

```
def image_tag(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.image.get_image()
```